# Why is Lishui University present in so many cities across the globe?

Tags: job-search, university, recruiting, china, scams

I'm searching for a postdoc and it seems that Lishui University recruits for its departments in Tokyo, Seoul, New York, Sidney etc. Typical job ad looks like [this.](https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/3636944951)

Not even biggest universities I know have that many offshore departments, and LU wikipedia page says nothing about their foreign activity. I visited their website linked on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lishui_University), but it is Chinese-only, and looks suspicious.

Is LU engaged in global recruitment tactic I don't understand, or is it a scam?

Answer (score 5):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but from the job ad it doesn't seem like they have actual physical offshore locations per-se, rather, they're hiring for a visiting professor, and listing the various countries in their job advertisments instead of "Mainland China" may get the job ad recommended to more potential candidates willing to make the trip.

While I can't say for certain that the jobs are 100% legit, my intuition is that the listings are more for greater advertising reach rather than being a genuine scam. Somewhat related, and not intended to be a sweeping generalization, but as someone who has grown up under Asian and specifically Chinese culture, there's always been the (mis)conception that lecturers from any foreign country are more experienced and knowledgeable than local ones. A university saying "we have lecturers from all over the globe" is enough to garner some perceived prestige from potential students.

Comment: "_there's always been the (mis)conception that lecturers from any foreign country are more experienced and knowledgeable than local ones._" Yes, being a native Chinese speaker, I can attest that this is very true.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a re-shoring tactic, to bring back researchers from outside mainland China. In the past I have seen similar geo-misplaced Linkedin ads from UNSW Sydney.

The page you posted does not look any more suspicious than Stanford University or Ritsumeikan University.

Whether it is a scam or not: if you can understand how to reach the responsible person for the advertised position outside Linkedin, do it and it will be clear.